# jQuery code not working for Instagram-clone-like course project

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, instagram-api

For a course assignment, I'm tasked with 'fixing' an instagram-like page that isn't working properly.

I need to render the hashtags from a tags list by creating an 'a' tag and an 'li' tag. eg. `'#beachday (4)'`
this is my (unsuccessful) code currently:

I assume the tags should show up with the photos that have been rendered on the page.

```js
function renderTags (tags) {
        var tagList = $('.tag-list ul');
        tags.forEach(function (tag) 
          var a = $('<a>').text('#' + tag.tags + '(' + tag.tag_count + ')');
        var li = $('<li>').addClass('u-pull-left');
        li.append(a);
        tagList.append(li);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Missing HTML here perhaps?</div>
```

I'm only beginning to learn CSS/html/jQuery so any help understanding where I'm wrong, or a point to any resource (looked at jQuery docs) is greatly appreciated.

~thank you

As I write the javascript code, the LiveServer webpage should reflect the code and changes and  at the moment none of my edits have produced results.

Comment: Sebastian, thank you for pointing this out. I have made the edit in my code, but unfortunately still in the same spot. My LiveServer still isn't responding.

Comment: `var div = $('').addClass('user-media-item u-pull-left');` - what should `$('')` be? I'm guessing it shouldn't be that, but something like `mediaItem.addClass(...)`, but I'm asking just in case.

Comment: Fiddling, thanks you for pointing this out. Perhaps it should be something else, <div> is the placeholder that was already on the file. I did try mediaItem, user-media, and media. Still no change on the LiveServer.

Comment: Do you have the example HTML you are using and not syntactically flawed/functional  JavaScript and how this function is called?  I started you off with a snippet

Comment: Note I also formatted this JavaScript which may perhaps reveal some of the flaws to fix rather than just spit out an answer since this is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

1.Ensure the forEach method is properly wrapped in brackets

2.Attach the 'href' attribute to the 'a' tag to make it clickable

```js
function renderTags (tags) {
  var tagList = $('.tag-list ul');

  tags.forEach(function (tag) {
    var a = $('<a>').text('#' + tag.tags + '(' + tag.tag_count + ')');
    a.attr('href', '#');
    var li = $('<li>').addClass('u-pull-left');
    li.append(a);
    tagList.append(li);
  });
}
```

Comment: This does not really do anything to actually impact the page DOM in question here.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thank you for your suggestions, I will certainly need to consider the 'href' attribute for later on in the assignment. Yes, still working on impacting the DOM - still working at it.